# Can people steal my icons?

Tags: glitch-2011

I've got some icons, nicely displayed in a row in my house:

[image]

If I have guests over, will they be able to pick them up and take them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as the icon's in your house, it's safe.

The Glitch Strategy Wiki seems to have my back:

> Using the Place verb will place the icon on the ground. The icon is safe when placed in your house. When placed elsewhere, anyone can pick it up.

Together we just tested this, and no, I can't take your icons.  I *can* take your butterfly milker (among other things left on the ground) but I can't access your storage cabinets, or disassemble your machines or the still.

Comment: Hmm, conflicting answers. Anyone trustworthy want to help me test this?

Comment: @fredley, yeah, sure.  Can you pull me to your house?

Comment: Yes, see you by the shrine at GFJ in a sec...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Don't give your key to anyone you don't trust.

Comment: Oh dear. I've had people in my house since I put them up - scary!